# How to move div X pixel to dynamically calculated position

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script which generates a div. This div is slightly offset. Is there an easy way to add 4px to the position. This is how Javascript generates the position:

```
top:"+a.nzOffset.top+"px;
```

i was thinking something like this:

```
top:("+a.nzOffset.top+"+4)px;
```

Comment: let's set style of div to `position: absolute`, add `top, left` to it and try

Comment: Sure you don't want to use margins for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know `div` id or css class applied to that `div`, then you can apply margin to move that div as

```
#divid{
   margin:10px;
}
```

Or

```
.divclass{
   margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: can't believe i didn't think of margin myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to move your div around

animate can do what you ask easy

```
$(object).animate()
```

see more information about this here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

and to update position:

```
 $(this).animate({ 'top': pos1.top + 'px', 'left': pos1.left + 'px'}, 200, function(){
        //end of animation.. if you want to add some code here
    });
```